# How to find last logged in user on Intune/Azure

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, intune

I am currently working on a project where I am needing to find the active **username**  (not the device name or hostname) of associates on the machines. Since there was no standard naming convention when the devices were provisioned, I am looking to find a way to figure out or see the last logged in users through Azure AD or Intune.

Not sure if I am making this post in the correct place, if not please be kind and suggest where I should post this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**To fetch the details of last logged on users on Intune, make use of below query in Microsoft Graph Explorer:**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/deviceManagement/managedDevices/{managedDeviceId}
```

The above query will only work on **beta version** of Microsoft Graph.

Please check the required **permissions** below:

[image]

In the output response, you can find the **`UserId`** and **`LastlogonDateTime`** in **usersLoggedOn** field.

In order to display the ***username*** via **`UserId`**, make use of powershell script mentioned in this [reference](https://svdbusse.github.io/SemiAnnualChat/2020/03/21/Changing-Intune-Primary-User-To-Last-Logged-On-User.html).

> **Note:** The Microsoft Graph API for Intune requires an [active Intune license](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=839381) for the tenant. **Beta version** is subject to change don't use it for production.

For more information, please **refer** below links:

[Get windowsManagedDevice - Microsoft Graph beta | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/intune-devices-windowsmanageddevice-get?view=graph-rest-beta)

[Find out last logon user of MDM assigned Coporate Device - Microsoft Q&A](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/335692/find-out-last-logon-user-of-mdm-assigned-coporate.html)